# Textmate Code Completion Question

Tags: ide, development-environment, textmate

I know the ESC key does code completion, but is there a way to get a pop-up(tool-tip I guess) that shows you all the possible choices for a piece of code?  As an example, it would be nice when writing Javascript to get a list of available actions.  Other apps I've used like Coda do this.  I'd like to check out Textmate but I have a hard time getting past this missing feature which I find pretty valuable, particularly as a fairly new programmer who likes to see what options are there as it's a bit of a learning tool for me also.  I thought I had found a plugin like what I'm looking for, Dialog2, but it seems to have disappeared as it was meant to be built-in to the never-released TM2.

I've looked around a fair bit for the answer to this question and figured this was my next best option.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have Textmate available to try it out, but I believe that option-Esc is supposed to show you the list of possible code completions.

Comment: I like you VERY MUCH right now Jacob!  Thanks.  Either the documentation failed to mention that or I'm blind as they come; almost certainly the latter.

Comment: Is there a way to make this the default action without needing to even press option-esc would have to be my follow up question

Answer (score 0):

Check out subtleGradient's tmbundle: https://github.com/subtleGradient/javascript.tmbundle

It knows how to auto-wrap for arrays, and objects. Documentation look-up too.