# Java code-completion in Textmate?

Tags: textmate, code-completion

I'm used to developing Java programs in Eclipse, where I can type something like... "SomeObject.", and when I press ".", it has a small list popup from which I can choose (and automatically complete) the method and variable names within that object.

I was wondering if there is any version of this functionality in TextMate?

Thank you.

Comment: This Question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570919/auto-completion-in-textmate-for-ruby

Comment: The nearest you can come to this feature is Option-Esc. This will bring up a list of completions Esc would offer you stepwise. It's still not the feature you asked for. I found this answer in the related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556391/textmate-code-completion-question/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [TextMate's FAQ](http://wiki.macromates.com/Main/FAQ):

> Q: Does TextMate have code completion, e.g. type a variable name and see all member data for that variable (object)?
>
> A: No.

Sounds like you don't want a text editor (like TextMate); you want an IDE (like Eclipse or Visual Studio).